# htaccess: only do [some lines of code] for one domain, no others

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication

Say I have a htaccess file shared by "dev.server" and "server.site.com".

The first domain should allow all users to access it unchallenged (it only exists on my local development server).

The second domain I want to authenticate users with Apache (NOT by database).

The code to authenticate users is:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Server Admin"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/passwd"
require valid-user
```

**What I can't do** is make those 4 lines only matter if the domain is "server.site.com". **How can I do this?**

I searched for something like `<IfEnv HTTP_HOST "site.server.com">` but had no luck.

Comment: Voters to close: Note: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work, still need to do some testing on it though.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

SetEnvIf Host domain.for.no.auth dev
Allow from env=dev

AuthUserFile .pwd
AuthType Basic
AuthName MySite
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this can't be done in a `.htaccess`  file. You'd have to put this into a [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) or [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) section, both of which can't be used in a `.htaccess` file.

You would have to define it in two separate files, or directly in the server's configuration in the `VirtualHost` section.